# Can I increase my DataTable and List<> iteration speed. C#

Tags: c#, list, performance, datatable, iteration

I hope you're all doing well.

I have a quick question regarding iteration. I've read several post about the speed of iteration and I couldn't figure how to make my iteration faster. Currently I'm doing something like this :

```
void Iteration()
        {
            //Creating and filling the datatable
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Datetime", typeof(DateTime));
            for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
            {
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                row["Datetime"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i);
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            //Creating and filling the list
            List<DateTime> _listDates = new List<DateTime>();
            DateTime _startDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
            for(int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
                _listDates.Add(_startDate.AddDays(i));

            //Here's the actual iteration
            foreach (DateTime _date in _listDates)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    if ((DateTime)row["Datetime"] == _date)
                    {
                        //Do something.........
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I fill a `List<DateTime>` and a `DataTable` with respectively 250 and 150 rows/line. I then want to compare the two values against each other and do something when there's a match. However, in my method that means 250 * 150 = 37500 passes. Now I could break out the loop when there's a match but that seems trivial to me since the match can also be on the bottom of the list and datatable. And in my program the average lists and tables have 2500 rows. So that's millions of passes every *n* minutes. Needles to say that this takes a while. I'm running this calculation on a separate thread so my program stays responsive.

Is there any way to make this smarter and/or faster ? Am I on the right track ?

Cheers,

Comment: maybe [Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=net-5.0) can help you - LINQ is much more efficient at matching up datasets than a simple nested loop.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Assuming we're talking an in-memory list, no it'll be exactly the same. We could speed this up by using another `List` instead of a `DataTable` (which are very slow due to boxing and other issues). We can also presize the lists: `new List<DateTime>(250)`. However this whole code is a bit daft (assuing *it is* the whole code). It would be far quicker to jump to the next month and just loop once 120 days, no lists or datatables at all

Comment: Can you pre-sort at least one of the collections? If so, it will be possible to perform a binary search on it.

Comment: Put the dates in  a HashSet then when you loop throught the rows do datesHashSet.Contains((DateTime)row["Datetime"] ) the contains method of hashSet is in O(1)

Comment: Do you want to `//Do something` only for the `DataRow`s that are between two dates, or you also want to do something for the dates that are not associated with any `DataRow`? In the first case it seems that a simple filter/sort LINQ query should be enough: `dt.AsEnumerable().Where(row => /*...*/).OrderBy(row => (DateTime)row["Datetime"]).AsDataView()`

Comment: Thank you all for such great support. I will create a benchmark test will all of the answers above. In fact, everything is usable as I don't have an restrictions or special needs. Pre-sorting unfortunately is not an options as I don't know when the event will occur. So a full iteration is unfortunately necessary.

Comment: @charlieface , what do you mean with a bit daft. As in .. outdated, obsolite ?

Comment: No, I mean the logic *as stated* (creating these two lists on the spot) seems like an absurd amount of energy to just doing a straight loop as I described. But if you have the `DataTable` and `List` existing already (you don't say so), then that changes things.

Answer (score 1):

What about this? this is more efficient because both data table and datetime list are scanned only once, and `HashSet.Contains` time complexity is O(1).

```
void Iteration()
{
    //Creating and filling the datatable
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Datetime", typeof(DateTime));
    for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
    {
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row["Datetime"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i);
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    //Creating and filling the list
    List<DateTime> _listDates = new List<DateTime>();
    DateTime _startDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
        _listDates.Add(_startDate.AddDays(i));

    var dateSet = new HashSet<DateTime>(_listDates);

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (dateSet.Contains( (DateTime)row["Datetime"]))
        {
            //Do something.........
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was faster :P, by the way, why do you create a list to put it in a hashset ? Wouldn't it be better to add directly to the hashset ?

Comment: @PierreMichel, yes you were. I didn't see your comment when I started writing my answer.

Comment: @PierreMichel, yes it would be better, but I assume you have the list first.

Comment: I'm going to try this as soon as possible. I'm going to read up on HashSets. Like Charlieface mentioned earlier, I'm not the most up-to-date programmer on the planet. I'll let you know how I went. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer me.